# using WorkerGlobalScope.importScripts() in typescript

Tags: typescript, import, service-worker

I am working on a service-worker for (Angular) web-apps. This service worker is made in Typescript. The web-app should serve the service-worker and a separate configuration.js file to configure the pre-build service-worker.

Because the configuration is unique for each web-app, it is required that the configuration is not directly included in the service-worker. I want to use the same service-worker for multiple web-apps.

using [WorkerGlobalScope.importScripts()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) it is possible to import external resources into a service-worker's global scope. But how will this work with typescript?

given the following code, how would one use importScripts() in typescript

```
interface IConfiguration {
    name: string;
}

let configuration: IConfiguration;

const initialize = (service: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope): void => {
    service.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
        console.log("Installing Service-Worker");

        service.importScripts("SWConfiguration.js");
        configuration = new service.SWConfiguration()  // <-- This won't compile

        return service.skipWaiting();
    });

    service.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
        console.log("Activating Service-Worker");
        event.waitUntil(service.clients.claim());
    });

    service.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {

        // Do something with the configuration

    });
};

initialize(self as any);
```

SWConfiguration.js would look something like:

```
public class SWConfiguration {
    name = "myName";
}
```

How would one import a configuration that is served in a different file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of additional searching/research, I have discovered nothing, **I think it is not possible at the moment.**

I have looked into the workings of the Angular Service-Worker and how that loads its configuration (which is configured using a JSON format). This service-worker will simply try to fetch the file from `/ngsw.json` and write the resulting configuration into the IndexedDB.
They also do some version checking using a hash. [Angular SW configurator](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/72eba7745fee1eacb4b4d076ce9f81dcb5d510ea/packages/service-worker/worker/src/driver.ts)
you can see the request on line 693;

```js
this.safeFetch(this.adapter.newRequest('ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=' + Math.random()));
```

While this is a more complicated solution, It is one that is proven to work.